# Two Primary Key for a table and primary key

Tags: sql

I want set two primary keys for a single table and in that one should be a foreign key in SQLserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are most likely looking for is a composite primary key, where two or more keys are combined to make up the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    key1 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    key2 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (key1, key2), 
    FOREIGN KEY (key2) REFERENCES otherTable (anotherKey),
    anotherField CHAR(100) NULL
)
```

Or, using the table designer: click the first key, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the second key, finally click the key button.

Comment: Actually in a table i have to set two columns as primary key.And in that one is reffering from another table so i have to set it as a foreign key because it's depend on another table

Comment: How to make one of that column as FOREIGN KEY

Comment: Im getting error"Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'siteConfig' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__myTable__key2__3B75D760'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
"

Comment: But im having the column name "name" in siteConfig table im trying to make it as foreign key

Comment: Is that `name` column marked as a primary key? See this for more on the error: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1776.aspx